# Reg expression to get value in between a tag in xml

Tags: regex

I am a newbie to regex.I need to extract text "2016-07-02T05:00:00" using the tag name.Can some suggest me how to do that.

```
<alpha:InboundEarliestDepartureDateTime>2016-07-02T05:00:00</alpha:InboundEarliestDepartureDateTime>
```

Comment: Is this specific to the tag you listed or any tag in general?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one: `(?<=>).*(?=<)`

Working example:

https://regex101.com/r/zH8rX1/1

Comment: Tnk u for ur help :)

Answer (score 0):

If you need the specific tag:

```
(?:<alpha:InboundEarliestDepartureDateTime>)([-0-9:T]*)(?:<\/alpha:InboundEarliestDepartureDateTime>)
```

If you need it in general, you can use Yaron's version.

If you need a no-lookaround version in general:

```
.*?>([^<]+)
```

The first capture group in both cases holds the desired value.